# apscheduler works perfectly on heroku but not on scrapyd locally

Tags: python, scrapy, scheduling, apscheduler

I dont know where I'm missing it but i have tried most options i know of. 
I have two scrapy projects, one deployed on heroku and the other on my local machine(due to issues arriving from using selenium on heroku)
The challenge i face comes from scheduling the projects to work at a given time everday or hour. 
In my heroku project deployed, i have the following code in a python file and also set the Profile with the clock varialble and it works fine

```
import requests
import pytz
from apscheduler.schedulers.twisted import TwistedScheduler
from twisted.internet import reactor

def send_posts():
    requests.post("https://hidden-heroku-link.herokuapp.com/schedule.json", data={
        'project':'project1js', 
        'spider': 'spider_name'
        })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler1 = TwistedScheduler(timezone=pytz.utc)
    scheduler1.add_job(send_posts, 'cron', hour='1', minute='25' )
    scheduler1.start()
    reactor.run()
```

**But running the using the same file in my project on my local machine, i can't seem to get it working**

**I Tried the following in a python file in the project directory**

```
import requests
import pytz
from apscheduler.schedulers.twisted import TwistedScheduler
from twisted.internet import reactor

def send_posts2():
    requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:6800/schedule.json", data={
        'project':'project2sel', 
        'spider': 'trends_ng'
        })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler1 = TwistedScheduler(timezone=pytz.utc)
    scheduler1.add_job(send_posts2, 'cron', hour='1', minute='25' )
    scheduler1.start()
    reactor.run()
```

Nothing popped up or came up.

**I then tried using schedule**

```
import schedule
import time
import requests

def job():
    requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:6800/schedule.json", data={
        'project':'project2sel', 
        'spider': 'trends_ng'
        })

schedule.every(20).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Then finally tried using cron**

> crontab -e

in editor

> 10 * * * * /usr/bin/curl curl http://127.0.0.1:6800/schedule.json -d projects=project2sel -d spiders=trends_ng

### I still couldn't get it to work

- The scrapyd server is up and running and if i run **curl http://127.0.0.1:6800/schedule.json -d projects=project2sel -d spiders=trends_ng**
  It runs perfectly

Comment: Did you try enabling debug logging as instructed in the [troubleshooting section](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html#troubleshooting) of the documentation?

Comment: By the way, if you're using "requests" then BlockingScheduler is probably the scheduler you want to be using.